# What should be the value shown for a collapsed custom date range picker?

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, ux-field, dropdown, selection

I'm working on a custom filter for a photo application. If the user wants to search for a photo, they can select from predefined date ranges or input a custom date range. Selecting a custom date range brings up a calendar.

When the user has selected a custom date range, this then collapses the select dropdown.

In the dropdown's collapsed state, should the value of this change from "Custom" to the actual selected date range (example: March 10, 2020 - June 10, 2020), or should it remain to say, "Custom"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The **selected values** are what give the data context and accuracy; 'custom' is just a signifier to the user of *capability to define a range*.

Go with the actual values, as without a clear display of time bounds, users might be wondering why their photos aren't showing up, only to realize that 'custom' might be set incorrectly, as they would have to store the date range in their working memory, rather than to see it on the screen.